# How to add a bottom toolbar in an html page

Tags: html, css

I want to add a bottom tool bar as shown below .

[image: toolbar]

I was trying with a code as below

```css
bottom-bar {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin:auto;
 height: 5em;
 width: 2em;
                    }
```

```html
<div class="bottom-bar">
  <table style="width:100%;">
   <tr>
    <td><img class="home" src="F:\images for apps\App_Icons-2016-07-07\App Icons\mood4.png">
    </td>
   <td><img class="statistics" src="F:\images for apps\App_Icons-2016-07-07\App Icons\charticon.png">
    </td>
   <td><img src="F:\images for apps\App_Icons-2016-07-07\App Icons\compass.png">
    </td>
   <td><img src="F:\images for apps\App_Icons-2016-07-07\App Icons\my profile.png">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

But I am not getting what I expect . And My result is as below 
[mytoolbarresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXCVs.png)

The images are big than i expected and the third images is not visible too.
How can I edit my code to get the expected result.
Thanks

Comment: You need to use `position: fixed` I think...

Comment: @karacsi_maci How would that help with the images?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. Add `width` and `height` style for images. add align center for `td`s. Check the path for 3rd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally avoid using a table, and go for `div` elements.

You can use flex-box to achieve this, and add a max-height to your images. That way you can add unlimmited links to your footer, it will allways look centered and aligned.

```css
.image img {
  max-height:25px;
}

.footer {
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.footer .image {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align:center;
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
  </div>
</div>
```